# link in email with special characters (php)

Tags: php, hyperlink, special-characters, html-email

My "Forgot password" page sends email (via PHPMailer ver-6.1.1) to the user, with a link containing his email address.
He then has to click on the link, which opens my **"resetPassword.php"** page where he can reset his password, with accordance to the email-address contained in the link.

Working fine, but NOT with email addresses containing the plus (+) sign (or any other special character, for that matter).

Relevant JS code to send mail:

`$body="http://localhost/myApp/resetPassword.php?frgt_psw_email=xxxx+1@gmail.com";`

which is exactly the link in the received email.

So far so good.

When clicking on the link the user is transferred to the "resetPassword" page, where the first thing I do (for debugging purposes) is:

```
echo $_GET['frgt_psw_email'];
exit();
```

What I get is: **xxxx 1@gmail.com**. As you can see, the plus sign is replaced by a space, and so the resetPassword functionality isn't working.

I tried replacing the + sign with htmlentities but that did not help.
I have also tried adding to my PHPMailer parameters :

```
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
```

which did not help either.

Please bear with me - I'm new to PHP and JS...
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `+` is a reserved URL character. You need to encode the query string values, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.

```
$body="http://localhost/myApp/resetPassword.php?frgt_psw_email=" . urlencode('xxxx+1@gmail.com');
```